# Best complexity to find solutions to $x^2+y^2=z^2$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, discrete-mathematics, searching

What is the algorithm with the best complexity that finds solutions in a given range to the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ ?

The best i could do is to iterate through all $x$ and all $y$ and store $x^2+y^2$ in a hash and then iterate through all possible $z$ and check if $z^2$ is in the hash.

Comment: The range is given. It should be [0,10^6].Yes, x,y and z are integers.

Comment: And the question is about algorithm complexity so isn't this what CS is about ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about [**Pythagorean Triples**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) (the form $x^2+y^2=z^2$ where $x$,$y$ and $z$ are integers).

**[Euclids Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple)** is generally thought to be efficient for finding primitive Pythagorean Triples.You can multiply these primitive triples with a constant to get non primitive Pythagorean Triples.

[**Here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples) are some other methods of finding Pythagorean Triples